# need help to add large data set using awk command

Tags: awk

My data look like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (10 columns) 
and
.
.
.
.
.
20,000 rows
```

I wanted to add only columns 6 and 7 until 16,000 row using awk command. I am pretty new in Linux and not very much familiar with awk. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $6+$7} NR==16000{exit}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` command you can do that also

```
cut -f6,7 -d' ' your_file|head 16000
```